# Line and text below

Tags: text-manipulation

I'm looking a way to do yield the following result in LaTeX.

[image]

As you can see, `(action)` is centered in the first clause of the text, and `(result)` is also centered in the second clause of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented by a `tabular`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\stackphrase}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}%
    #1\\\relax(#2)%
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
  \stackphrase{if you go to bed late,}{action}
  \stackphrase{you'll be tired}{result}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]